# SQL Insert Update on tables with Select causing Locks and wait issue may using MERGE

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

We have two database tables : PointsMaster (PM) and PointsDetails (PD), the requirement here is to check if PM table has currentbalance of greater than "x" and if it is greater than "x" then update the PM table's currentbalance (i.e. reduce currentbalance by "x") and then also put a new record in the PD table about this "x" points.

If the currentbalance is lower than "x" then no updates to PM table and no insert to PD table.
If currentbalance is NULL then simply we need to return back null.

Right now writing these individual:-  SELECT and then UPDATE (PM) and INSERT (PD) is causing lock issues and I am thinking of using "MERGE" (on PM Table) so I can do SELECT and UPDATE in one transaction and not cause any locks on PM table but my issue here is how do I check if CurrentBalance is Null or Lower than "X" and return that back so that processing can happen for those 2 conditions (i.e. of Null balance or when balance is less than "x").

MERGE can help me here with SELECT and if MATCHED UPDATE on PM.. but the INSERT on PD has to happen only if UPDATE on PM happened else not and also if Balance is lower than "x" or Null I have to return that back and not UPDATE PM or ADD record to PD.

Any help here? As the code we have is causing locks and waits and is not efficient with volume of data. PM and PD tables have required indexes in place.

All of the above is being done from C#.Net in a Azure hosted Function App.

Thinking of following SQL Code

```
Declare @rcount INT;

MERGE PointsMaster as tgt
Using PointsMaster as src
ON (tgt.ProfileID = src.ProfileID)
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.ProfileID ='3589153' and tgt.CurrentBalance > 50000000
Then UPDATE SET tgt.CurrentBalance = tgt.CurrentBalance - 5;
Set @rcount= @@ROWCOUNT;

if (@rcount > 0)
Begin
INSERT INTO PointsDetails ( PointsHeaderID,Debit,Credit,ActionTypeCode,TransactionDate) Values (3587854,5,0,'AT2',Getdate())
End
if (@rcount = 0)
Begin
SELECT * from PointsMaster where ProfileID = '3589153'
End
```

Comment: You ought to be able to `select` and `update` in one `update`. An `update` _on one row_ can return _before_ and _after_ values for columns. Throw in a `case` expression to decide whether the column value should change and it's done. (`update Foo set @Before = Column, @After = Column = case when ... then Column - 5 else Column end where ...;`) Check the the variable(s) to determine whether or not the `insert` is needed. If you need to handle multiple rows then you could use an `output` clause to get the intermediate (before and after) data.

Comment: Thank you @HABO I will dig a bit about the UPDATE command and the CASE statement you mentioned (I am not a SQL or TSQL developer but I will google around it and try to use and report back here).

Comment: Be careful using MERGE: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/